# Ice Skating near Tokyo/Nikko in the Summer

Tags: japan, tokyo, winter-sports, nikko

I was hoping to enjoy some Ice Skating, *just for fun* during my trip to Japan.

I am currently in Tokyo and was planning to visit Nikko sometime soon. I was hoping if there are any ice skating rinks around Tokyo or Nikko where I can indulge in the same?

Most seem to be open only during the winters, but I believe there should be some synthetic ones which should be open in the summer as well.

Comment: Use the Googles, my friend.  First hit for "tokyo ice skating": http://www.timeout.jp/en/tokyo/feature/335/5-to-try-Tokyos-ice-skating-rinks and the last two are open all year.

Comment: @jpatokal Ayy ze googles! Didn't see that link! There are two parks which *should* be open. Any experiences with them?

Comment: @jpatokal I was also kind of worried if I would be taken aback by the pros... I'm just looking to go for fun. Cuz I enjoy ice skating! I think I'll try these out! :D

Comment: No, which is why I didn't post that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Lonely Planet book for Tokyo](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=0y6tz1o5EcYC&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=tokyo%20ice%20skating%20summer&source=bl&ots=esi2FGp6Ti&sig=7adnvB4ukK2KpAg06MmTNtOQXjE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ud1tU7OCEcW6kAXw84CoBA&ved=0CGQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=tokyo%20ice%20skating%20summer&f=false), page 196, it mentions two:

[Takadanobaba Citizen Ice Skating Rink](http://whereintokyo.com/venues/25195.html):

> Takadanobaba / Skating rink Open noon-7:45pm (Sun. 10am-6:30pm).
>
> Open  every day.
>
> Y1300 all day; skate rental Y500
>
> Takadanobaba 4-29-27.

and [Meiji Jingu Ice Skating Rink](http://www.meijijingugaien.jp/english/ice-skating.html):

Open year round, you can use ice hockey, speed or figure skates.  Rentals are Y500, rink is NHL sized and discounts are available after 3pm. Fees vary (see page).

Comment: I visited the Takadanobaba Citizen Ice Skating Rink. What a lovely experience! :D Thanks!